# the image first loading using function is hide when again the function happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

JavaScript for `drag&drop` and `resizing`. Now when I click a button I can load a image in a canvas and it is draggable. But when I click second time the first image is vanish, and new one is coming I want both images. This is the code I'am using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <img src="icon_03.jpg" id="my-image">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
            var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
            var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
                left: 100,
                top: 100,
                angle: 30,
                opacity: 0.85
            });
            canvas.add(imgInstance);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are creating a canvas object in your function, so there is always a new canvas, which is empty created and drawn over the existing one.
I updated your fiddle, so that whenever you click on the button, a new image is added to the canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/z4fty1de/7/

this is my code:

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');
$('#image').click(myFunction);
function myFunction() {
            var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
            var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
                left: 100,
                top: 100,
                angle: 30,
                opacity: 0.85
            });
            canvas.add(imgInstance);
};
```

I hope I could help you. :)